# Tournament table Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to make a tournament table and I need to:
make A1 cell type amount of points based on score (B1 is player 1 score, C1 is player 2 score)

I want it to automatically detect wins, draws and loses and base on it to give the correct amount of points (3, 1, 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate player 1 score with:

```
=arrayformula(ifs(B4:B="","",C4:C="","",B4:B<C4:C,0,B4:B=C4:C,1,B4:B>C4:C,3))
```

see this [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10K-sXDncptZflenPlivyV8xxDIBA58DQaN8jaIO-1Fg/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: scores]

Comment: Okay that works fine but nbot at my sheet, i guess i am jsut too stupid for this. Can you tell my how to copy that so it may work?

Comment: i found out how to do it, thank you!